# Может ли std::bind быть удобнее, чем лямбды?

Tags: c++, stl, boost, asio

Поковырялся с `asio`, и наткнулся вот на какой момент. Для привязки handle'ров к функциям асинхронного чтения/записи используется `bind`: в примерах - из `boost`, я без особых проблем заменил на `stl`. Например:

```
socket_.async_send_to(asio::buffer(*message), remote_endpoint_,
      boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_send, this, message,
        asio::placeholders::error,
        asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

И ниже по тексту:

```
void handle_send(boost::shared_ptr<std::string> /*message*/,
  const asio::error_code& /*error*/,
  std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)  {  }
```

Но в процессе "щупания" изрядную часть кода я переписал (в первую очередь для отвязки от `boost` - шеф и на header-only версию `asio` смотрит косо). И везде намного удобнее было написать лямбду:

```
socket_.async_send_to(asio::buffer(*message),remote_endpoint_,
                    [](const asio::error_code&,std::size_t){});
```

Поэтому вопрос такой: есть ли какие-то области применения, где `std::bind` или `boost::bind` остаётся единственным или более удобным способом, чем лямбда-выражения? Стоит ли подробно изучать `bind`, или достаточно на пальцах представлять, чтобы при необходимости разобраться в чужом коде - а в своём он не понадобится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне кажется, по удобству синтаксиса создание функциональных объектов через `std::bind` и тому подобное проигрывает по выразительности лямбдам.

Тем не менее, я бы всё равно разобрался в том, как работает `std::bind` (и даже попробовал бы реализовать его вручную, чтобы прочувствовать проблематику). Знания карман не тянут.

Кроме этого, возможное применение старой функциональности:

- чтение и понимание чужого кода
- программирование под среду, которая имплементирует старый стандарт
- не исключено, что на вашей платформе старый метод будет производительнее, и это будет критично для вашего кода

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Итог: из очереди "надо изучить" не выкидываю, но ставлю низкий приоритет. :)